# How to access all nodes from NodeParameterDefinition in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a Jenkinsfile that use the [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) for jenkins. Here I use the NodeParameterDefinition to give the user the ability to select nodes where the build should happen. I have enabled allowMultiSelectionForConcurrentBuilds, but I only still get a string with only one node name when accessing the parameter value in the Jenkinsfile. The parameter value type is also a string, how can I get all the nodes the user selected for the parameter?

paramter definition:

```
 [
     $class: 'NodeParameterDefinition',
     allowedSlaves: ['ALL (no restriction)'],
     defaultSlaves: ['master'],
     description: 'What nodes to run the build on.',
     name: 'BUILD_NODE',
     nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility'],
     triggerIfResult: 'allowMultiSelectionForConcurrentBuilds'
 ]
```

So if I select multiple nodes when executing, I still only get one node name when accessing this parameter value.

```
echo "Will build on $BUILD_NODE";
```

Is multi node selection was enabled not possible with pipeline scripts?

How I access the parameter value:

```
echo "Will build on $BUILD_NODE";
node("$BUILD_NODE")
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Progress: I figured out that I need to access the parameter as "params.<param name>. So I need to use params.BUILD_NODE to get the correct object as env.BUILD_NODE and BUILD_NODE is only a string representation. But now I have a new problem, and that is that the parameter is a null object.

Answer (score 3):

[NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodelabelparameter) doesn't work smoothly with Pipeline and [Blue Ocean](https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/), just as it is not updated frequently (see the [revision history](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin#NodeLabelParameterPlugin-VersionHistory)). Jenkins Plugins must follow [requirements](https://jenkins.io/doc/developer/plugin-development/pipeline-integration/) in order to be compatible with Pipeline.

Unfortunately the issue is still unresolved (unknown when it will be resolved):
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43720

> The problem is that I can not use env.NODE_PARAM or NODE_PARAM to get
>   multiple selection of nodes, as those are only a string representation
>   of a single node.

You can vote for this jira-task JENKINS-43720 (click *"Vote for this issue"*), or participate in the plugin development.

So far I found my clumsy way to imitate the plugin behavior by using another parameter option **choice** (but this works in Blue Ocean!):

```
properties([
    parameters([
    choice(choices: ["none", "node_1", "node_2"], description: "", name: "NODE_1"),
    choice(choices: ["none", "node_1", "node_2"], description: "", name: "NODE_2")
    ])
])
// here you can write your behaviour 
// e.g. validation of params, e.g. if 'none' is selected, then use the default node_X
node(env.NODE_1) { }
node(env.NODE_2) { }
```

or you can use the option **string**:

```
properties([
    parameters([
       string(defaultValue: "node_1, node_2", description: "", name: "NODE", trim: false)
    ])
])
// parse here the param env.NODE
```